# Retrofit in android - use object Instead of array in json

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I use Retrofit  for  get and Parse Json but I have problem with it

show me this error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

my json

```
 {
"status": "ok",
"item": [
{
"name": "joe"
},
{
"name": "jack"
},
{
"name": "sara"
}
]
}
```

My interface

```
    public interface api{
    @GET("/api/get.php")
    Call<List<Repo>> listRepos();
}
```

MainActivity

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        api service = retrofit.create(api.class);

        Call<List<Repo>> call = service.listRepos();
        call.enqueue(this);
```

and

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(Response<List<Repo>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new RepoAdapter(response.body());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        for (Repo repo : response.body()) {
            Log.i(TAG, repo.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e(TAG,t.getMessage());
    }
```

My Model

```
public class Repo {



       private String name;
        private  String status;

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


    }
```

and i Can Not parse 
can anybody help me. thanks

Comment: Please show your Repo class

Comment: i add my model .now what should i do? .thanks  a lot

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your retrofit interface expects a list, but that's not what your API is returning. You need a class that can represent the response body correctly, such as the following:

```
class ListReposResponse {
    String status;
    List<Repo> item;
}
```

Then your retrofit method needs to return that class instead of `List<Repo>`.

```
@GET("/api/get.php")
Call<ListReposResponse> listRepos();
```